# POSIX (C++) parameter type mismatch

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

i have a function named race, with Fleet* object as parameter:

```
    void* race(Fleet* fleet){
        //some code here
    }
```

and another posix thread argument:

```
    vector<Fleet*> allfleet; //value has been passed/stored, ignore 
    pthread_create(&t[i],NULL,race,allfleet.at(i));
```

however error appeared at the race argument in the pthread_create line

```
    error: Incompatible function parameter type "void *" and "fleet*"
```

ive tried everything, conversion, casting, nothing works.

note: no other error present, just the type mismatch

edit:

it seems like the signature requires

```
   void* function (void*)
```

but instead race is

```
   void* fuction (Fleet*)
```

Comment: Is this the example you are running? Since the error you are getting, does not seem to match the code you are showing us (remember, C++ is case-sensitive language!).

Comment: Try defining `race` with the correct prototype.

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages. No compiler would use the word "param".

Comment: Take a look at `pthread_create` signature, write out types of each parameters, then write out types of parameters that you are passing and compare.

Comment: it seems like the signature requires
void* function (void*) 
but instead race is
void* fuction (Fleet*)

Comment: "it seems like the signature requires void* function (void*) but instead race is void* fuction (Fleet*) " Well the compiler is trying to tell you just that. What compiler are you using? The error message is not the best in the world.

Answer (score 2):

[`pthread_create` call requires `void *(*start_routine) (void *)` argument](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). Your function is incompatible with it. Try:

```
void* race(void* data) {
    Fleet* fleet = (Fleet*)data;
    //some code here
};
```

If you are using C++11 I advice using [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of pthread calls.

Comment: This is correct. OP should have just read the documentation (and the error message)!

Comment: thanks, it helps. im kinda new with multithreading, so passing around pointers type makes me confused. at first i thought casting/conversion would help.

Comment: *If you are using C++11 I advice using std::thread instead of pthread calls.* But for *learning* how threads work, I'd think using the pthread calls would be better - on a POSIX platform, C++ `std::thread` is almost certainly implemented using pthreads.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's precisely the reason why std::thread is better IMO: it is platform independent. As a bonus it handles argument packing/unpacking for you.

Comment: @freakish But if you learn pthreads, `std::thread` is easy, as are MS Windows threads.  Also, having `std::thread` do all the work for you means you don't learn about how threads actually access data passed from the parent thread, for example.  Sure you can more portable **C++** code using `std::thread`, but what about when you're trying to learn how to be a portable *programmer* that can write more than C++ code on more than one platform?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, that's one approach. My approach is to not care about underlying details as long as I don't have to. Most of the time I'm not interested in *how exactly* threads work. I'm only interested in the result. It's a basic idea of abstractions that whole programming world is built upon. So normally you don't really wanna learn how threads work unless you are dealing with a problem that std::thread doesn't solve. So I guess we can at least agree to disagree. :)